# Which Falcon 9 (1.0 or 1.1) core has fuel cycled the most?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, reuse

This question is related to reuse possibilities. One of the things that affects reuse is thermal cycling of the fuel tanks. (Consider how microfractures in the X-33 composite tank killed that project. Ok, political lack of will killed it, but that was the excuse).

Thus the question. With the DSCOVR Falcon 9 launch, Feb. 2015, we saw the core do the following fuel/defuel events:

- McGregor testing: 1 fuel/burn it out. (We know they are all tested with a burn at Texas site)
- Wet dress rehearsal: 1 fuel/defuel, 1-3 second burn.
- First attempt, Feb. 8: 1 fuel/defuel
- Second attempt, Feb. 10: 1 fuel/defuel
- Third attempt, Feb. 11: 1 fuel (hopefully 1 launch, recovery, and eventually reuse).

Which F9 core has done the most of these cycles? There have been lots of scrubs, delays, tests, failed wet rehearsals, etc.

Comment: Surely it would be the F9R Dev 1 (Grasshopper v1.1). Any particular reason why you're excluding that one?

Comment: @TildalWave I did not think of that one. Though I would say GH1 was fueled more times than GH2.

Comment: According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grasshopper_%28rocket%29, GH1 flew 8 times. I would presume that it also underwent an acceptance test, so there's 9 propellant cycles. F9R dev 1 flew 5 times before it self-destructed, so assuming it also underwent an acceptance test, there's 6 times for the 1.1 architecture. I'm not sure about specific missions that might have required more cycles due to scrubs, like the DSCOVR mission you pointed out.

Comment: @Nickolai Make that an answer!  We can build on that answer.

Answer (score 2):

Building on TidalWave's observation, I've found the following from wikipedia:

Grasshopper 1.0 flew 8 times. I would presume that it also underwent an acceptance test, so there's **9** propellant cycles.

F9R dev 1 flew 5 times before it self-destructed, so assuming it also underwent an acceptance test, there's **6** times for the 1.1 architecture.

I'm not sure about specific missions that might have required more cycles due to scrubs, like the DSCOVR mission you pointed out.